# Const pointer to volatile struct member

Tags: c, embedded, constants, volatile

I'm using microcontroller to make some ADC measurements. I have an issue when I try to compile following code using -O2 optimization, MCU freezes when PrintVal() function is present in code. I did some debugging and it turns out that when I add `-fno-inline` compiler flag, the code will run fine even with PrintVal() function.

Here is some background:

AdcIsr.c contains interrupt that is executed when ADC finishes it's job. This file also contains ISRInit() function that initializes variable that will hold value after conversion. In main loop will wait for interrupt and only then access AdcMeas.value.

```
AdcIsr.c
static volatile uin16_t* isrVarPtr = NULL;

ISR()
{
    uint8_t tmp = readAdc();
    *isrVarPtr = tmp;
}

void ISRInit(volatile uint16_t *var)
{
    isrVarPtr = var;
}
```

```
AdcMeas.c

typedef struct{
    uint8_t id;
    volatile uint16_t value;
}AdcMeas_t;

static AdcMeas_t AdcMeas = {0};

const AdcMeas_t* AdcMeasGetStructPtr()
{
    return &AdcMeas;
}
```

```
main.c

void PrintVal(const AdcMeas_t* data)
{
    printf("AdcMeas %d value: %d\r\n", data->id, data->value);
}

void StartMeasurement()
{
    ...
    AdcOn();
    ...
}

int main()
{
    ISRInit(AdcMeasGetStructPtr()->value);
    while(1)
    {
        StartMeasurement();
        WaitForISR();
        PrintVal(AdcMeasGetStructPtr());
        DelayMs(1000);
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is there something wrong with usage of const AdcMeas_t* data as argument of the PrintVal() function? I understand that AdcMeas.value may change inside interrupt and PrintVal() may be outdated.
2. AdcMeas contains a 'generic getter'. Is this a good practice to use this sort of function to allow read-only access to static structure? or should I implement AdcMeasGetId() and AdcMeasGetValue functions (note that this struct has only 2 members, what if it has 8 members)?

I know this code is a bit dumb (waiting for interrupt in while loop), this is just an example.

Comment: `isrVarPtr` is a pointer, but `tmp` is  an integer. You should be getting a warning for `isrVarPtr = tmp;`

Comment: Maybe you meant `*isrVarPtr = tmp;`?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, typo, yes I meant `*isrVarPtr = tmp;`

Answer (score 0):

Some bugs:

- You have no header files, neither library include or your own ones. This means that *everything* is hopelessly broken until you fix that. You cannot do multiple file projects in C without header files.
- `*isrVarPtr = tmp;` Here you write to a variable without protection from race conditions. If the main program reads this variable in several steps, you risk getting incorrect data. You need to protect against race conditions or guarantee atomic access.
- `const AdcMeasGetStructPtr()` is gibberish and there is no way that the `return &AdcMeas;` inside it would compile with a conforming C compiler.

  If you have an old but conforming C90 compiler, the return type will get treated as `int`. Otherwise, if you have a modern C compiler, not even the function definition will compiler. So it would seem that something is very wrong with your compiler, which is a greater concern than this bug.
- Declaring the `typedef struct` in the C file and then returning a pointer to it doesn't make any sense. You need to re-design this module. You could have a getter function returning an instance to a private struct, if there is only ever going to be 1 instance of it (singleton). However, as mentioned, it needs to handle race conditions.

Stylistic concerns:

- Empty parenthesis `()` in a function declaration is almost always wrong in C. This is obsolete style and means "accept any parameter". C++ is different here.
- `int main()` doesn't make any sense at all in a microcontroller system. You should use some implementation-defined form suitable for freestanding programs. The most commonly supported form is `void main (void)`.
- `DelayMs(1000);` is highly questionable code in any embedded system. There should never be a reason why you'd want to hang up your MCU being useless, with max current consumption, for a whole second.

Overall it seems you would benefit from a "continuous conversion" ADC. ADCs that support continuous conversion just dump their latest read in the data register and you can pick it up with polling whenever you need it. Catching all ADC interrupts is really just for hard realtime systems, signal processing and similar.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, This code is not meant to do anything useful, I just want to demonstrate this const AdcMeas_t* AdcMeasGetStructPtr() concept and get some feedback if this is a good practice to handle IRQ or should I make getters for every read-only variable in AdcMeas_t that I need to access. `If the main program reads this variable in several steps, you risk getting correct datas` - I don't really get it, should I disable interrupts even when I'm reading this variable? The microcontroller is using ARM-Cortex M0+ core and it is able to update this variable atomicly.

Comment: @KRol Disabling interrupts is one way to do it, but then you will lose ADC reads. But that's only a concern in the kind of applications where it actually makes sense to use every ADC sample - doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @KRol It doesn't matter what CPU you have. This is the C language itself which cannot guarantee atomicity (unless you use C11 _Atomic). Typically the machine code generated from `foo = bar;` is to read `bar` from memory into a register, then store that register value at the address of `foo`. Doesn't matter the slightest if your CPU is 32 or 128 bits wide - it's not an atomic access still.

Comment: Ok, so my idea with generic getter in this case is not the best. If I would like to read AdcMeas.value from struct I should disable interrupts (or use _Atomic) and do it inside getter whereas AdcMeas.id can be read with no problems.

Comment: @KRol Yep, though you should disable the specific ADC interrupt rather than the global interrupt mask. As an alternative, you could come up with some double-buffer sceme where the ADC is storing data in one variable but you are reading from another - this could be used to solve re-entrancy. Also, you could include lightweight digital filters inside the ISR if you want, since ADCs are noisy by their nature. Something like a median-3 or moving average filter can be placed inside an ADC ISR. More complex filters could be placed in the getting function.

Comment: @KRol [This post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409545/using-volatile-in-embedded-c-development/409570#409570) might also be helpful, concerning when to use volatile and how to share data between an ISR and the main program.